# Frozen last row of DataGridView as the sum of the columns?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to make the last row of a `DataGridView` as the sum of the columns, and that the last row always will show/be frozen?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is actually very simple, and just requires you to think outside the box a little.

Usually, once data is loaded into your grid view, there's a dark grey row at the bottom of it:

[image]

You can use this space to your advantage. All you need to do is drag a few labels onto your form, placed just inside your grid view, with a background colour applied:

[image]

Within your code, add a method like this:

```
void UpdateTotal(Label Label, int Number)
{
    // Called from another thread; facilitate safe cross-thread operation
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(new Action<Label, int>(UpdateTotal), new object[] {Label, Number});

    // Called from this thread or invoked
    else
        // Format the number with a thousands separator
        Label.Text = Number.ToString("N0");
}
```

Then, from wherever you update your grid view, call `UpdateTotal(labelPostsAffected, 2000);`, using the name of your label, and the sum you've calculated (or calculate it in the method).

The result is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Firstly you have to iterate through the grid and calculate the sum of the required columns
after calculating the sums you have to create a new DataGridRow and populate it with the calculated values, set the Frozen property of the DataGridRow to True then add the new DataGridRow to the Datagridview. [Sum Column Values in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363312/display-sum-the-values-of-the-cells-of-last-column-in-datagridview)

Instead of creating a new DataGridRow you could just add a new row with the summed values on your data source then find the last row on your DataGrid and set the property of that row to Frozen=True

Answer (score -3):

To do this you have to set **ShowFooter** attribute of **True**

and then in code behind add your desire value in the footer

---

```
   <asp:GridView ID="grdList" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" >
   // other part of gridview codes e.g columns or blah blah blah
   </asp:GridView>

   // in code-behind
   int totalValue = 2 * 10;
   grdList.Columns[2].FooterText = totalValue.ToString();
```

Comment: i cant find this attribute, where i can find it ?

Comment: @Gold is talking about Winform `DataGridView` and you are suggesting code of ASP.Net `GridView`.