# Display sum the values of the cells of last column in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows

How to display the sum of values of the cells of last column in datagridview.
i have a grid with 2 columns name and value.
i want the grid to have a textbox with sum of values in the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have integer values in your last column, you could use something like this:
EDIT: you should check whether the the current Row is new row (the one for inserting)

```
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            int num = 0;
            if(!dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow)
                if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1].Value.ToString(), out num))
                    sum += num;
        }
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Total", sum.ToString()});
```

If you have some other type of number you should parse that number insted.
****EDIT:****As stated in the comments, you have a `DataGridView` Control that is data bound. In this case you should add data to the source for the binding. In case that is a `DataTable`, you should add to it instead of adding to `DataGridView`.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Total" , sum.ToString() });
```

Comment: i've coded almost like this, added 'dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Total", sum.ToString()});' to it. i m gettng an error like 'Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound'.

Comment: decimal sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < grd_vw_Deductns.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDecimal(grd_vw_Deductns.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            }
            grd_vw_Deductns.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Total", sum.ToString() });

Comment: You are using DataBinding for your DataGridview, therefore you can't add new row, If you want to set the sum into the TextBox, just remove the last line and write textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();.

Comment: ya, i ve placed it nd ve done so. i would like to know whether it is possible to show the sum in last row..

Comment: What is the source for the databinding? Is it a DataTable or what?

Comment: grd_vw_Deductns.DataSource = objPayRoll.LstPayRollED.FindAll(x => x.EdType == "D");
          grd_vw_Reimbrsmnts.DataSource = objPayRoll.LstPayRollED.FindAll(x => x.EdType == "E");

Comment: List<PayRollED> LstPayRollED , objects of class PayRollED

Comment: It looks like you should either add another object of your class to the list or use other controls for total. If you add the total to the list be careful to remove it afterwards. The only way is to add new item to the source.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var value = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(x =>
                                                                {
                                                                  double val = 0;
                                                                  if (double.TryParse(x.Cells["Column"], out val))
                                                                    return val;
                                                                  else
                                                                    return 0;
                                                                });
```

That should do it for you using LINQ.

Comment: I am getting the sum value Luke, but could'nt add a row at footer of datagrid and show that sum there....

Comment: Well your question doesn't clearly state that so therefore you should ask another question on how you get a value in the footer of a datagrid. My answer answers your question for getting the sum of columns in a datagridview.

Comment: "i want the grid to have a textbox with sum of values in the last row."

Comment: i've mentioned it in my question.