# How to make last row in a dataGridView on a Windows Form to be displayed all the time while still allowing the remaining rows to scroll

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dataGridView which has about 30 rows in it and last row of it contains sum of all the cells in that particular column. Now I would like to freeze the last row which has sum while still allowing the remaining rows to scroll.

```
dataGridViewPaymentsReceived.Rows[dataGridViewPaymentsReceived.Rows.Count-1].Frozen = true;
```

> The above code freezes the entire dataGridView and doesn't allow me to scroll on it. 
>   Can anyone suggest me a good way to keep the last row displayed all the time even when I scroll on the dataGridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create a second DataGridView directly below the first.  Then manually populate it with the single row that you want to be displayed every time the first datagrid binds to data.

To make it appear totally seamless, don't forget to hide the column headers in the 2nd datagrid:

```
dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17458134/183624) for more info.

Comment: this needs more code to work such as synchronizing the `Column Width` between the 2 datagridviews, there are some other data-related issues.

Comment: @KingKing: Certainly.  I figured it went without saying, or that the OP would use the UI to size his columns accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @ajax81,but I have more number of dataGridViews on my Form. SO, adding an additional gridview for each existing gridviews might not be an efficient way.

Comment: @Dayakar: Create a single custom control that has both grids in it, and use the custom control in multiple place in your app.

Comment: @ajax81: I would like both grids to look like one, but when I use two grids, As I have more number of columns, it displays horizontal scroll bar after the first grid which gives me kind of weird look to the grid, Is there any way I can embed the second grid within the first grid. Thanks